# Does using the Facebook post in more buy/sell groups integrated feature with many groups trigger spam warnings from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-groups

I was using the "post in more (buy/sell) groups" integrated Facebook feature (I'm translated the feature name from Spanish so I don't know how exactly it's called in English). I didn't have problems until some days ago. Recently when using it to share the same item in around 80 groups, it started to trigger "your post is spam" messages. I'm not exactly sure if it's because I'm sharing the post in many groups (I used to share it in around 75 with no problem) but I can't see absolutely anything in my post that could make them "spam" other than it is shared in many groups. In a way this makes no sense because why would Facebook encourage you to use a feature that allows you to share a item in many groups at the same time and then complain you are posting it in many groups, but something similar happened when they introduced the invite persons to your fan page feature. So my question is, Does using the Facebook post in more buy/sell groups integrated feature with many groups trigger spam warnings from Facebook? Or do I have to suppose my posts are being marked as spam for another reason? I asked Facebook for an answer about this, but they don't reply.